# How to make content scripts match new tabs in firefox addons/extensions?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, content-script

I know normally you just set the URL next to matches like - `"matches": ["<all_urls>"],` but I could not find any documentation of what the URL is for new tabs in firefox, I could only find that URL for chrome.

Heres my manifest.json -

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "TestExt1",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon1.png"
    },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["TestExt1.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

I read another post on here about making a button opening a new tab using "_blank", so I tried setting my matches to `"matches": ["_blank"],` in the manifest file but that did not work. I have confirmed my issue is not with the javascript file because it works on every other URL.

How can I set my scripts to only make changes to new tabs?

Or is this something I have to make happen within the content script files themselves?

Comment: Use [chrome_url_overrides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_url_overrides).

Answer (score 0):

the default new tab page with the tiles is `about:newtab`

the default home page is `about:home`

for a blank page use `about:blank`

See the `about:about` page for available about pages.

Comment: Thank you for that. I kept digging and found out that content scripts don't work under the context of matching about pages